# How to detect Point to Point VPN when peers are my softwares

Tags: networking, network-programming, vpn, openvpn

I am trying to develop a utility, that runs on two peers in a network. The job is to identify if the network is actually a VPN. An important property to be noted is - the peers mostly belong to different networks in different offices in different geographies. One important property of this setup is the peers are assumed to be in same subnet. If they are not, communication is not allowed.

The peers connect to each other using a TCP connection. After establishing connection peers exchange connected IP Addresses of both machines. Then the two software pieces compare the network part of it(they get the net mask from adapter), with that of itself. If the two networks do not match, it is declared as VPN.

However, this mechanism cannot be used in point to point VPNs.

```
I check if the adapter is a software adapter.
I could also exchange public IPs to know if our public IPs are different.
I could exchange MAC addresses/description of the connected adapters and compare them.
```

But to me all this seems to be symptomatic tests and not a definitive test.

Need ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Every test you're able to use that is network-based will be "symptomatic." Point-to-point VPN software is designed to present the same layer 3 interface to you that IP on top of Ethernet would, so you won't be able to detect "VPN software" in general. Here are a few ideas you could use:

- Can you test latency (maybe compute round-trip time on one side)? If it's greater than a few milliseconds, you're probably going across a WAN network. This would indicate you're either using some sort of VPN, the Internet, or an MPLS-style "metro ethernet" link.
- Do you know what VPN software could be running? Check running processes to see if any of them look like VPN software you know about.
- If this is for your employer, then is it possible to just set a flag in your software (or file on the machines it's running on, etc) with the office location it's running at? If so, just exchange the locations and check if they're different.

As an aside, your original test to check if the network prefix is different will not accurately detect a VPN -- it will run into false positives when there's more than one subnet in use on a LAN (common even in small business networks).

Depending on your actual use case, one of these methods is quite likely to be sufficient.